# PSQL filter each group of rows

Tags: postgresql

Recently I've faced with pretty rare filtering case in PSQL.
My question is: How to filter redundant elements in each group of the grouped table?

For example: we have a nexp table:

```
id  |  group_idx  |  filter_idx
 1          1             x
 2          3             z
 3          3             x
 4          2             x
 5          1             x
 6          3             x
 7          2             x
 8          1             z
 9          2             z
```

Firstly, to group rows:

```
SELECT group_idx FROM table
GROUP BY group_idx;
```

But how I can filter redundant fields (filter_idx = z) from each group after grouping?

P.S. I can't just write like that because I need to find groups firstly.

```
SELECT group_idx FROM table
where filter_idx <> z;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? It seems you can either use `HAVING` or tricks with RANK OVER (PARTITION BY filter_idx), but it would be nice to have more clarity on the question, i.e. to see table in between, are you using aggregates and so on.

Comment: what can you not use `GROUP BY` and `WHERE..` in one query ?  What is not behaving like you want, wen you do so ? What is desired output (of the final query) ?

Comment: I've edited the question (added a few table rows). No, I don't use aggregates

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to get in the end. So, you have a query with groups (1,2,3). If you don't do aggregates, then your group by will be exactly the same as `select distinct group_id from t1`, so you can filter.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide input and desired output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to see all groups at all times, even when you filter out all records of some group:

```sql
drop table if exists test cascade;
create table test (id integer, group_idx integer, filter_idx character);
insert into test
(id,group_idx,filter_idx)
values
(1,1,'x'),
(2,3,'z'),
(3,3,'x'),
(4,2,'x'),
(5,1,'x'),
(6,3,'x'),
(7,2,'x'),
(8,1,'z'),
(9,2,'z'),
(0,4,'y');--added an example of a group that would be discarded using WHERE.
```

Get groups in one query, filter your rows in another, then `left join` the two.

```sql
select  groups.group_idx,
        string_agg(filtered_rows.filter_idx,',')
from 
    (select distinct group_idx from test) groups
    left join 
    (select group_idx,filter_idx from test where filter_idx<>'y') filtered_rows
        using (group_idx)
group by 1;
-- group_idx | string_agg
-------------+------------
--         3 | z,x,x
--         4 |
--         2 | x,x,z
--         1 | x,x,z
--(4 rows)
```